# Django QuerySet API inverse field lookup

Tags: django, postgresql, django-queryset, searchqueryset

I'm wondering if it is somehow possible to use "the inverse" of the `__contains` fields lookup.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#contains

So for example:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    ...
    last_name = models.CharField()
```

And with this `Person` model I could do for example the following query that'll return the Persons that have a `last_name` field that would fit in the string given:

```
>>> Person.objects.filter(last_name__contains='John Doe, Jane Roe, ...')
<QuerySet: [Person: Donald Doe]>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
import operator    
from functools import reduce
from django.db.models import Q  

Person.objects.exclude(reduce(operator.or_, (Q(last_name__contains=x) for x in ['John Doe', 'Jane Roe', '...'])))
```

is the same than:

```
Person.objects.exclude(Q(last_name__contains='Jhon') | Q(last_name__contains='Jane'))
```

you can change `operator.or_` by `operator.and_`

Comment: Well, this is looking for the Person objects that have either 'John Doe', 'Jane Roe' etc in their `last_name` field. So this is still not inverted unfortunately.

Comment: So what I eventually would like is the Person objects that for example have `last_name="Doe"` if I do `Person.objects.filter(last_name__invertedcontains="John Doe, Jane Roe")` (explicitly single string, though not important here)

Comment: @White srry I misunderstood the question let me correct

Comment: @White see my edit, instead of use `filter` put `exclude`

Comment: Sorry, now still it does only return objects with for example `last_name="John Doe"`. Annoying isn't? :=>

Comment: if the `last_name__contains="Jhon Doe"` it will return all the objects with the last name jhon doe it seems you are looking for doe last name, so it wont return it. In this case use `operator.and_` to exclude